# custom style rules on html and body tags with react jss, @global does not get applied

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss

i am attempting to apply custom style rules to: all elements, html, and body tags using react jss, in a React TS library.

when the component inspected in storybook the '@global' rules non present

here is the relevant code section:

```
import React from 'react';
import jss from 'jss';
import { AppShellProps } from '../interfaces/AppShellProps';
import { StyledThemeContextProvider } from 'ui-context';

const globalStyles = {
    '@global': {
        '*': {
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
        },
        html: {
            fontSize: '16px',
            overflowY: 'hidden',
            overflowX: 'hidden',
        },
        body: {
            width: '100%',
            minHeight: '100vh',
        }
};

export const AppShell: React.FC<AppShellProps> = ({ ...props }) => {
    const { classes } = jss
        .createStyleSheet({
            shellMain: {
                border: '3px dashed purple',
            },
            ...globalStyles,
        })
        .attach();

    return (
        <main className={classes.shellMain}>
            <StyledThemeContextProvider themeName={props.themeName}>{props.children}</StyledThemeContextProvider>
        </main>
    );
};
```

and here is the result of the inspection:

[image]

***Q:*** how would it be possible to achieve to apply the globalStyle style rules. and stay close to the react jss implementation? or simply just what do i do wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out i had left the jss import when i was experimenting, i replaced

> import jss from 'jss';

with:

> import { createUseStyles } from 'react-jss';

and the **classes** is implemented like such:

```
export const AppShell: React.FC<AppShellProps> = ({ ...props }) => {
    const classes = createUseStyles({
        shellMain: {
            border: '3px dashed purple',
        },
        ...globalStyles,
    }).apply({});

    return (
        <main className={classes.shellMain}>
            <StyledThemeContextProvider themeName={props.themeName}>{props.children}</StyledThemeContextProvider>
        </main>
    );
};
```

this implementation results in global style rules get applied:

[image]